# Short exact sequences of topological groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, general-topology, topological-groups, exact-sequence

Suppose that $G$ is an abelian topological group with a descending filtration $(G_n)_n$ of subgroups.

Suppose that $0 \to G' \xrightarrow{f} G \xrightarrow{g} G'' \to 0$ is an exact sequence of abelian groups.

Then $(f^{-1}(G_n))_n$ and $(g(G_n))_n$ are descending filtrations of subgroups in $G'$ and $G''$ respectively.

The topologies induced by these filtrations are the subspace and quotient topologies respectively.

Viewing $0\to G'\xrightarrow{f} G \xrightarrow{g} G'' \to 0$ as an exact sequence of **topological** groups, is it true that
$$G/f(G')\cong G''$$
as **topological** groups?

Any help gratefully received!

---

**Edit in response to Moishe Cohen's comment below.**

*Question 1.* How do the $(f^{-1}(G_n))_n$ and $(g(G_n))_n$ make $G'$ and $G''$ into topological groups?

We define topologies on $G'$ and $G''$ by declaring the descending filtrations of subgroups mentioned above to be neighbourhood bases for $0$ in $G'$ and $G''$ respectively. By homogeneity, this in turn defines a unique topology on $G'$ and $G''$ which is compatible with the respective group structures.

*Question 2.* How do we show that the induced group isomorphism $G/f(G')\xrightarrow{\bar{g}} G''$ is continuous?

To show that a group homomorphism of topological groups, say $\phi:H\to H',$ is continuous it is sufficient (by homogenity and the fact that $\phi(0)=0$) to show that, for any neighbourhood $N$ of $0$ in $H',$ the preimage $\phi^{-1}(N)$ is a neighbourhood of $0$ in $H.$ We apply this in our case...

Note that the quotient topology on $G/f(G')$ is exactly the topology determined by the filtration:

$$(G_1+f(G'))/f(G')\supseteq (G_2+f(G'))/f(G') \supseteq \ldots$$

Now let $N$ be any neighbourhood of $0$ in $G''.$

Then $N$ contains some $g(G_n)$ and so $\bar{g}^{-1}(g(G_n))\subseteq \bar{g}^{-1}(N)$ and $0 \in \bar{g}^{-1}(g(G_n)).$

We clearly have that $(G_n+f(G'))/f(G')\subseteq \bar{g}^{-1}(g(G_n)).$

This establishes continuity of $\bar{g}.$

---

**Completion of the proof: $\bar{g}$ is an open map.**

Let $N$ be any neighbourhood of $0$ in $G/f(G').$

Then $N$ contains some $(G_n+f(G'))/f(G')$ and so

$$\bar{g}(N)\supseteq \bar{g}((G_n+f(G'))/f(G'))\supseteq g(G_n).$$

Hence we are done, as before.

---

**Post mortem.**

The proof boils down to the following identity:

$$g(G_n)=\bar{g}\big((G_n+f(G'))/f(G')\big).$$

Comment: How does a filtration induce a topology on a group in your question? Do you declare this filtration to be a base of topology at the identity? Also, please, provide your own thoughts about the question. For instance, do you know how to prove continuity of the natural map $G/f(G')\to G''$?

Comment: I have added my thoughts along these lines :) I would be very grateful if you could tell me whether what I've done is correct. It now remains to prove that $\bar{g}$ is an open map.

Answer (score 1):

A good choice for a counter-example are normed vector spaces, since they also are abelian topological groups.

Let $\lVert\cdot\rVert_1  $ and $\lVert\cdot\rVert_2 $ be two inequivalent norms on a vector space $X$. Then the identity map
$$ \text{id} \colon (X, \lVert\cdot\rVert_1+ \lVert\cdot\rVert_2) \to (X, \lVert\cdot\rVert_1) $$
can not be an isomorphism, otherwise $\lVert\cdot\rVert_1  $ and $\lVert\cdot\rVert_2 $ would be equivalent